# MoveIt: Is it possible to have different types of controllers in one planning group?

Tags: moveit, ros-melodic, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

as the question suggests, is it possible to have inside one MoveIt planning group, for example: a FollowJointTrajectory controller along with an effort_controllers/JointPositionController?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351755/moveit:-is-it-possible-to-have-different-types-of-controllers-in-one-planning-group?/) by [JunTuck](https://answers.ros.org/users/26970/juntuck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 87 on 2020-05-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like each planning group connects to a single action server advertising the respective action (e.g. `/follow_joint_trajectory`), but since you can combine multiple planning groups into another one, you should be able to use that meta planning group to control your two subgroups which use different controllers.

If that doesn't work, you could write a custom controller for your robot that accepts the `FollowJointTrajectory` goal, passes part of it to a "real" FollowJointTrajectory controller and then does something else for a few of the joints.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-19**:
At least the `joint_trajectory_controller` from `ros_control` can be configured to accept partial goals (ie: for only a subset of joints).

This may not need any custom controllers.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-05-19**:
I was actually unsure and looked into it a little more. I updated my answer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-19**:
Well I'm not sure about the MoveIt side. I just wanted to point out the fact that partial goals are supported, so this could work without needing custom code.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer has already been given in the discussion. Any type of `controller` can be grouped into a planning group.
The trick is to define the `group` in `roslaunch moveit_setup_assistant setup_assistant.launch` and check if `Pose` is actually possible. And since the Generate Package generates a `.srdf` file, you should be able to use it in your Moveit by copying or editing a part of the group into your package.

---

Originally posted by [jahad](https://answers.ros.org/users/54843/jahad/) with karma: 21 on 2020-05-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1